# Moving Coins (find winning strategy)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, recreational-mathematics

I have question about exercise Coin Slide on page 149 I found in
"Thinking Mathematically" by Mason, Burton and Stacey. Here it
is:

[image]

I was able to solve it successfully for $3-3$ case (original problem)
and $4-4$ as well  by try and error "strategy". But I'm looking for a conceptional strategy which can be extended to 5-5, 6-6, ...n-n cases.
Let denote by $B$ the big circle, by $S$ the small circe,
and by $-$ the gap of length of big circle and $.$
the gap of length of small circle. Then the possible solutions for
$3-3$ and $4-4$ are:

[image]

Problem: I solved these two cases more less by try and error
and unfortunatelly I ain't recognized a general "winning strategy"
which can be successfully extended to $n-n$ case. The reason why
I think that there exist such general winning strategy to attack every
$n-n$ case is author's hint in the exercise: Remember Leapfrogs.

The Leapfrog exercise on p 52 is:

[image]

And the important thing is that elaboration of simpler cases of this
exercise reveals a strategy that can easily applied to general cases:

[image]

That is the straight forward Leapfrog strategy is that after every move the colours in the row should alternate.
The point is that since the author gives this Leapfrogs
exercise as hint for my original Coin Slide problem, I think that
there should be also exist a general winning strategy to attack it
independent of $n$ in the $n-n$ case. Does somebody see how this
exercise is related to Leapfrogs and what is the successful
strategy in this game?

Comment: Are you asking about the generalization of [Interactive Coin Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49928/32666) ?

Comment: yes and not. of course the problems are similar, but in this question the number of big coins coinside with number of small coins, in yours not. That is my question treats a special case and generalizes it in a special direction, namely that we we start with $n$ big and $n$ small coins. But of course I'm also interested in strategies which generalize your question: that we start instread by say $n+1$ big and $n$ small coins.

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution: Let $n = 4k + r$.  The problem is solvable if $r = 0, 1, 3$.

The solution is actually very easy.  Starting with the original pattern, working on the right side, using the OP's solution for $n=4$, we can arrange the last $8$ coins into `ssssBBBB` while not touching all other coins.  Now that the `ssssBBBB` is established, we can move them all far away (i.e. some long distance away but still along the row) by moving them as `ss, ss, BB, BB`.

Do this repeatedly until there are $r <4$ pairs of coins left, and now we just need to arrange these remaining coins.  If $r=0$ or $1$, they are already arranged, and if $r=3$ we can use the OP's $n=3$ solution to arrange them.  Finally, re-assemble the whole row by moving all those far-away pairs back and attaching them to the correct end.

The only difficulty is the $r=2$ case.  If $n=2$, I think the puzzle is unsolvable.  The case I'm still undecided is $n=6$: Certainly my approach above won't work (since $n=2$ seems unsolvable), but is there a more clever way to solve $n=6$?  I don't know.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Although I have to admit that I doubt that to argue in this way was the idea of the book's author (and found nowhere a online solution). The most difficult hurdle for me here is to find out how this exercise is related to Leapfrogs exercise. I think that this would reveal the strategy intended by the author. Thinking about the strategy used for Leapfrog there was a kind of simple motto for each upcoming move: the colours must alterate. If after your move this property is preserved, the move is correct, otherwise it's a wrong move.

Comment: And I conjecture that for this exercise there exist a similar (maybe more complicated) march route to attack it, otherwise why the reference to Leapfrogs as hint?

Comment: I did not read too much into the author's two-word comment "Remember Leapfrogs!" :) But you are the one reading the book, so perhaps you're more right than I am.  The Leapfrogs rule is a sort of "invariant", which is of course a standard way to solve puzzles.  My solution here is a "divide & conquer", which is another standard way to solve puzzles.  Ah well, if I ever solve the $n=6$ case I will post again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy that I think works but I can't say that is optimal. For simplicity, let's assume I can move more than 2 coins but always an even number. For example, moving 8 coins at once is the same as 4 moves of 2(as long as I am careful with the moves). Also, let $L_S$ denote the largest length of consecutive small coins and $L_B$ respectively of big coins.

- Step 1: Pick an $SB$ from the middle and move it to the end
- Step 2: Pick the $SS$ from the end and move it to the front
- Repeat steps 1 and 2 until it's not possible to do so

The invariant is that after every couple of steps either $L_S$ or $L_B$ will be increased by one.

Example: $5-5$

$Loop\ 1: bsbsbsbsbs \\
 Step\ 1: bsbsbsbsSB \\
 Step\ 2: SSbsbsbsbb \\
 Loop\ 2: ss\_bsbsbs\_bb \\
 Step\ 1: ss\_bsbsSB\_bb \\
 Step\ 2: ss\_SSbsbb\_bb \\
 Loop\ 3: ssss\_bs\_bbbb  
$

Close enough! Note that for even $n$ it would have worked as the outer $S...S$ and $B...B$ are always of even size. Let's finish the job for odd $n$. Just move the remaining $BS$ in the front and then the $S...S$ in the front and we are done.

Comment: I not completely understand your strategy in case $5-5$.  Let
consider the Loop 1. we start with $BSBSBSBSBS$. Your Step 1 is is to pick an $SB$ (arbitrary?) from the middle and
move it to the middle. Let eg take the $S$ number $3$ and
$B$ number $4$ and move it to the end. We obtain: $BSB.-SBSBSSB$ with a gap $.-$ in the positions $3$ and $4$.

Comment: Then we do Step 2: Pick the $SS$ from the end and move it to 
the front. We obtain:

$SSBSB.-SBSB..B$.

But what we do with the two gaps? (recall $-$ is the gap of
length of $B$ and $.$ of lenght of $S$).

Comment: The problem I would like to point out is: assume we have $S--BSB$. There is no legal move to close there the $--$ gap by one step.

Comment: Do you consider the gap sizes to be different?

Comment: Yes, for example a gap in $BS--.-SBS$ has length of $3$ big coins and $1$ small coin. More precisely the sum of the lenghts of their diameters.

Comment: If that's the case then how is your solution for 3-3 correct? In your third step, you fill a small gap with a big coin.

Comment: You probably mean the $2.$ step, don't you? 
I mean firstly, we start with $BSBSBS$, then I move the
block $SB$ at position $(4,5)$ to the end. Then I obtain
a gap of length $.-$ (or $-.$ That doesn't matter since only the LENGTH of a gap is important). Then
I fill it with $BS$ from the front. (that works as
$-.$ has exactly the length of $BS$. And then I bring $BB$
(after last step it's on the front) to the end. After 2. step there are no gaps in the game.

Comment: Yes, third line, second step. I understand now what you mean by the gaps. I used _ simply as a delimeter, note how the outer SSS and BBB doesn't change. To be honest, I didn't understand from your question that thing about the gaps. Let me see if I can adopt my algorithm to suit this case as well.